# How can I modify this little endian method so that it won't return a negative integer?

Tags: java

```
public static int liEndVal (Byte[] mem) {
    return (mem[0] & 0xFF)
| ((mem[1] & 0xFF) << 8)
| ((mem[2] & 0xFF) << 16)
| ((mem[3] & 0xFF) << 24);
}
```

How can I modify this method so that when my input is for example 45 A2 BD 8A the little endian integer output will not be a negative integer? I don't understand why does it keeps on returning the two complement integer.

Answer (score 1):

When `mem[3]` > 0x7F, the returned `int` will be negative, since the max value of `int` is `0x7FFFFFFF`. If you want a positive returned value, return a `long`.

```
public static long liEndVal (Byte[] mem) {
    return (mem[0] & 0xFF)
    | ((mem[1] & 0xFF) << 8)
    | ((mem[2] & 0xFF) << 16)
    | (((long)mem[3] & 0xFF) << 24);
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to modify the main function though

Comment: @Tree If you are not allowed to modify that method, this probably means that negative returned values are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because in that representation, the (signed) integer **is** negative. Looks like you need an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here is probably actually that you shouldn't mind that the answer is negative: just treat it as unsigned, and the signedness of the output as unimportant.  You cannot eliminate the possibility of negative output, but I think you're wrong that it matters.